# extracting number after certain words in a text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a big text file and I would like to extract only numbers that are after certain phrases/words.

There are dozens lines in this huge text file in the following format:

> Best CV Model for car: 15778 is order:2 threshold: 0 with AUC of :
>   0.7185 gene aau_roc: 0.466281

One solution is to just look at number after "for car: X", "is order: X", "threshold: X", "Y gene aau_roc: X" !

At the end I would like to have 15778, 2, 0, 0.7185, 0.466281 for each line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> if line.startswith('Best CV Model'):
...     re.findall(r'\d+\.{0,1}\d*', line)
... 
['15778', '2', '0', '0.7185', '0.466281']
```

Comment: That pattern is certainly simpler than the one I came up with, but its downside is that it will match numbers on lines that don't match the structure of the line the questioner was looking for.

Comment: @Blckknght in theory your solution might be the more perfect one, in real life it is often smart to take the 'softer' solution and thus also parse lines that might have spelling errors like `threhsold` instead of `threashold`. I'd go with this solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already tagged your question with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), I suspect you're already close to a solution. You can write a regular expression pattern that will match all the numbers on your line. Something like:

```
pattern = r"for car: (\d+) is order:(\d+) threshold: (\d+) with AUC of : ([0-9.]+) gene aau_roc: ([0-9.]+)"
```

Note, I've made this to exactly match your example string, including some odd spacing around the `:` characters in a few places. Double check that it actually works with your real data.

To use this to do a search of your text file, I'd use `re.finditer` to search over the whole text and return an iterable:

```
import re

for model, order, threshold, auc, aau_roc in re.finditer(pattern, text):
     do_stuff()
```

Comment: Yes, I would like to use regex, using re.finditer gives me the following error ! Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logparser.py", line 10, in <module>
    re.finditer(pattern, head)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 186, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: and my code is like this with open("test.log") as myfile:
    head=list(islice(myfile,100))

pattern = r"for car: (\d+) is order:(\d+) threshold: (\d+) with AUC of : ([0-9.]+) gene aau_roc: ([0-9.]+)"

re.finditer(pattern, head)
print model

Comment: @user702846 Ah, if you're reading the file into a list of lines you'd want a different search code. I was assuming you had the whole text in a string. Try `matches = [re.search(pattern, line) for line in head]` or something to that effect.

Comment: the file, is 1gig, and the part I am looking must be in first 1000 lines. I will check it out ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
re.match('(?<=for car: )/n*',the_line);
```

Just keep repeating for the other variables you need, and store them in your desired output.